# How to check input radio from a button - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a work a simple task without lucky, I'm trying to **check** an input radio by clicking on a button. Each input radio as their button. How do you achieve that in angular way?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">

        <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="1">

</button>


<button class="btn btn-primary">

        <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="2">

</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary">

        <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="3">

</button>
```

How you can see I put the input inside the element button, if you have different thoughts please correct me.

Comment: Why not just check the radio by clicking on the radiobutton?

Comment: Correct, i tried to that and it works but the problem is that angular validation give me that value as `required` even if I checked it with Jquery `prop` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the associated `ng-model` equal to the `value` of the radio you want selected:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="color = 1">
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" ng-model="color" value="1">
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<label>` and style it as button:

```
<label class="btn btn-default"> Button 1
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="1">
</label>

<label class="btn btn-default"> Button 2
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="2">
</label>
```

and add css to hide the `input[type="radio"]`.

Not everything needs Angular.

Comment: Wow, your solution is clever. I would like to accept your answer for the cleanest way to achieve it. But because is an angular related question I will accept that one above. But keep in mind I really appreciated this.

Comment: @Fabrizio, when you have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.